# Issue filtering out an array of strings from Set | Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to filter out an array of strings `removeArray` from a Set `mySet` that contains those string values :

```
struct ListStruct: Codable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

var mySet: Set<ListStruct> = []
mySet = Set(initialArray)

let removeArray = removeSet{$0.name}
```

**Filtered Out**

How can I properly filter out removeArray from mySet? Below is my attempt, not quite sure how to handle the array of string values.

```
mySet = mySet{$0.id != removeArray.contains($0)}
```

Comment: What is the type of `removeArray`?

Comment: It’s a string array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be looking for something like this:

```
let mySet: Set<ListStruct> = [.init(id: 0, name: "name 1"),.init(id: 1, name: "name 2"),.init(id: 2, name: "name 3"),.init(id: 3, name: "name 4")]
let namesToFilter = ["name 2","name 4"]
let result = mySet.filter { !namesToFilter.contains($0.name) }
print(result)
```

Which would leave the items with `"name 1"` and `"name 3"`.

This works by doing a `filter` and checking to see if the `namesToFilter` contains an element with an equal `name` property.

Similarly, if you wanted to test the `id` property instead:

```
let mySet: Set<ListStruct> = [.init(id: 0, name: "name 1"),.init(id: 1, name: "name 2"),.init(id: 2, name: "name 3"),.init(id: 3, name: "name 4")]
let idsToFilter = [0,2]
let result = mySet.filter { !idsToFilter.contains($0.id) }
print(result)
```